# Filter products by sku number in admin

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, sku

I need to have SKU in product list in admin panel "OC3.0.2.0" and if that possible to have it in filter at same place. Is here anybody can show me the way to solve this small problem.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify controller, language, model and template files to add SKU filter in admin product list page, where its lengthy process.
I just modified this pages but can paste the whole code here because code is more than 30000 characters. I created a zip file with modified files.

If you are using default theme please download this files from this [link](https://ufile.io/s8hgq) and replace the default files with new files

If you are using a customized theme you can download the extension from this [link](https://ufile.io/165tz).

[image: Demo]

**Note:** If SKU is not Mandatory then please remove the autocomplete from the product list. Otherwise, it creates displays empty fields in its column.

Please Open product_list.twig from admin/view/template/catalog

and remove the following code from it

```
$('input[name=\'filter_sku\']').autocomplete({
'source': function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_sku=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item['sku'],
                    value: item['product_id']
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
'select': function(item) {
    $('input[name=\'filter_sku\']').val(item['label']);
}
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Great but I mean for search sku in admin product list on OC3.0.2.0!

Comment: @Navid Yes... I Created the extension for same... You can see the answer ( I updated)... and please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: Great Work Ziauz, Why the SKU column is empty and nothing is shown there? How could this problem be solved?

Comment: @Navid can see an image of it?  Did you filled SKU values in product... If not that might cause an empty column... if SKU is not mandatory then please remove the autocomplete.I just updated the answer how to do it

Comment: All data of product in my site entry with sku code, but in admin product list sku column is empty!  What is problem?

Comment: @Navid can I See screenshot or can you share the link if possible

Comment: Could you please send me your email address so that I can send you the Login information?

Answer (score 0):

I created a free extension for this to help the community. Here is the link:

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=38074

Designed to work for Opencart 3.x version.